# Suitable file type for combined raster and superimposed geometric data?

Tags: java, image

I am creating a java application in which you can trace the composition of a photo or image by drawing lines or shapes over the image, e.g. drawing the horizon line/ vanishing point/parallel lines/outlines. Thus you get a data set in addition to the raster data which you can analyse and compare to other images, e.g. by comparing line equations.

My question is: What would we a suitable file type to contain both the raster (rgb+alpha) data of the image and the geometric data of the traced-over composition lines?

Comment: Have you considered using (and serializing) a custom class that combines a BufferedImage and a List of appropriate geometric primitives?

Comment: Just looked up java serialization (i'm pretty new to it) and that looks like a excellent solution-cheers.

Comment: no problem, glad to help :)

Comment: would you mind accepting my answer if it helped you out? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider making a custom class whose members are the image you're describing and a list of the appropriate geometric primitives, e.g.:

```
class GeometricImage {
    public BufferedImage image;
    public List<Line2D> lines;
}
```

And then, assuming you don't require interoperability with non-Java applications, you can simply use Java's [serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) facilities to write or read the instances from or to a file.